# How do I correctly get a URL for a resource on the classpath in WebSphere 6.1?

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, classloader

The code below works beautifully in Tomcat, but the call to getResource(...) returns null in WebSphere 6.1.  I've tried using both Thread.currentThread().getClassLoader() and MyClass.class.getClassLoader() - both return null.

```
    URL url = null;
    ClassLoader cl = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
    LOG.info("Using class's classloader.");

    url = cl.getResource("resources/AConfigFile.xml");

    if(url == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The ClassLoader returned null for the URL of the " +
                "the XML Document.  This is definitely not right.");
    }
```

...and I have also tried this, with no luck...

```
   URL url = null;

    url = MyClass.class.getResource("resources/AConfigFile.xml");

    if(url == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The ClassLoader returned null for the URL of the " +
                "the XML Document.  This is definitely not right.");
    }
```

What's up with this?  How do I properly get a URL for a resource on the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess the difference is the way the `ClassLoader`s behave. Can you use the `Class` variant instead? MyClass.[class.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)? We use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` under WebSphere 6.1 all the time.

Or perhaps try prefacing your resource path with a leading slash.

Using the `Class` variant, your relative path will look in the `resources` subdirectory under the package of `MyClass`. But the `ClassLoader` variant might not.

Comment: I've tried the class variant.  No luck.  But I've got money on the leading slash fixing the problem...rebuilding to test now...we'll find out shortly :)

Answer (score 1):

Within a servlet container, you should use [`ServletContext.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and  [`ServletContext.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead of [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) and [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) respectively. It's more likely to behave consistently across different servlet containers.

Also, double check that your relative path is correct in the context you're using it in. Try an absolute path and see if that works any better.

Comment: "This method has a different purpose than java.lang.Class.getResource, which looks up resources based on a class loader. This method does not use class loaders." The `Class` methods definitely work in WebSphere.

Comment: @dbreaux: The `Class` methods may "work" for you, but if you're loading a resource that's within your web application, it's advisable to use the methods in `ServletContext`. That's what they are designed for. As it turns out, the leading slash was enough to help the container find the resource and that solved the OP's problem. But I would still recommend switching to the `ServletContext` methods too.